# Ending a LongLivedReadTransaction correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, yapdatabase

I have 1 VC having a LongLivedReadTransaction fetching review objects. When I press a button it presents a second VC having another LongLivedReadTransaction fetching repository objects.

However when I present the second VC it calls the grouping block from the transaction grouping the review objects.

So my question is: How to properly end and start a LongLivedReadTransaction ?

Comment: Do each of your VCs have their own database connections or are they sharing one database connection?

Comment: I outsourced them to a CollectionViewDataSource and they each create a new connection. But somehow they call the same grouping block.

Answer (score 0):

This question was also discussed on the YapDatabase mailing list here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/yapdatabase/W6k6f7mUyJU